# Добавление реакции на существующие сообщение

Tags: c#, discord

Мне нужна помощь с discord.net, мне нужно добавить реакцию на уже **существующие** сообщение. Единственный способ(других не нашел) это `RestUserMessage`, вот его построение `await message.AddReactionAsync(emoji);`. Вопрос в том что я не знаю как определить переменную `message`?

Пробовал это способ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740554/discord-net-adding-reactions-to-a-socketmessage. Но выдает ошибку "Message not found".

Comment: Ну вы должны наверно сначала найти нужное сообщение, не? Обычно оно ищется по ID, а чтоб найти сообщение по ID, вам надо у канала вызвать метод `.GetMessageAsync();`, в который уже и передаете нужный ID и вот уже потом ставите реакцию.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Попробовал найти 
`var v = await channel.GetMessageAsync(804360074541662220);` ,
не получилось. Ошибка 'Message not found.'"

Comment: Ну значит в этом канале нету такого сообщения. Смотрите что за `channel` у вас, все-ли вы делаете так.

Comment: В том и проблема что все уже проверял по несколько раз. Может ли это быть проблемой самого сервера или его настроек(права боту выданы)?

Comment: Права на чтение канала как минимум должны быть. Попробуйте получить чисто ради интереса все сообщения текущего канала (`GetMessagesAsync()`) и посмотрите, а есть-ли там ваше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ:

Для начала создаем метод.

```
private async Task MessageReaction(ISocketMessageChannel channel, ulong msgId, string emojiId)
```

В методе определяем сообщение к которому хотим добавить реакцию.

```
var msg = await channel.GetMessageAsync(msgId);
```

Так же проверяем сообщение.

```
var usermsg = msg as IUserMessage;
if (channel == null) { return; }
```

Создаем переменную "емодзи" и добавляем к сообщению.

```
Emoji emoji = new Emoji(emojiId); // Сайт с EMODJI ID https://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/list.htm
await usermsg.AddReactionAsync(emoji);
```

PS: Полный код:

```cs
[Command("react")]
private async Task MessageReaction(ISocketMessageChannel channel, ulong msgId, string emojiId)
{
    // Определение msg
    var msg = await channel.GetMessageAsync(msgId);

    // Проверка сообщения
    var usermsg = msg as IUserMessage;
    if (channel == null) { return; }

    // Создание переменной "емодзи"
    Emoji emoji = new Emoji(emojiId); // Сайт с EMODJI ID https://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/list.htm

    // Прикрепление эмоджи к сообщению
    await usermsg.AddReactionAsync(emoji);
}
```